# Is there a way to schedule script every day using Suite Script 2.0?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I Want to create Suite Script 2.0 which will search and get data from saved search but I want to schedule this script to run every day at specific time.

Is there a way to execute script on specific interval in Suite Script (ScheduledScript)?

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple options like [Map/Reduce](https://3626311-sb1.app.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4685231336.html), [Workflow](https://3626311-sb1.app.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4101527388.html), [Scheduled Script](https://3626311-sb1.app.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_1506710621.html) and [Mass Update](https://3626311-sb1.app.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N668529.html) in NetSuite to schedule a script and it would run automatically.

In *Map/Reduce* and *Scheduled Script*, you will have to read saved-search in your script itself, whereas *Workflow* and *Mass-Updates* run on provided *Saved-Search*.

> Is there a way to execute script on specific interval in Suite Script (ScheduledScript)?

Yes, you can schedule any of the above mentioned scripts to run at specific intervals or run daily, weekly etc.

Comment: Thank you Avi, but can I do this with Suite Script? For reference, What sort of coding I need to do in Suite Script to execute every day.

Comment: For example: If i create suite bundle with suite script and then when other user install that bundle then included suite script need to auto schedule to run every day.

Comment: If you look at links above, NetSuite has provided basic working examples with all of them. For map/reduce or scheduled script you will have to write map/reduce or scheduled script respectively, where as for workflow you need to write Workflow Action Script and Custom Mass Update script for Mass Update. All of these will be part of your said bundle along with their scripts, which will be deployed or user can deploy it as needed(to run on specific time).

Answer (score 0):

The SuiteScript API docs show three different ways to run a Scheduled Script:

1. Recurring with the NetSuite UI
2. On demand with the NetSuite UI `Save and Execute` button
3. Submitting an on demand task using `task.ScheduledScriptTask`

Source: `https://{yourAppId}.app.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4658507760.html`

They are missing the 4th way: defining it via XML.

In `customscript_scheduled_test.xml`, I have:

```xml
<scheduledscript scriptid="customscript_scheduled_test_1">
    <name>Scheduled Script Test 1</name>
    <notifyowner>T</notifyowner>
    <scriptfile>[/SuiteApps/{yourAppName}/ScheduledScript.js]</scriptfile>
    <scriptdeployments>
        <scriptdeployment scriptid="customdeploy_scheduled_test_1">
            <isdeployed>T</isdeployed>
            <loglevel>DEBUG</loglevel>
            <status>SCHEDULED</status>
            <title>Scheduled Script Test 1</title>
            <recurrence>
                <daily>
                    <startdate>2020-01-01</startdate>
                    <starttime>00:00:00Z</starttime>
                    <everyxdays>1</everyxdays>
                </daily>
            </recurrence>
        </scriptdeployment>
    </scriptdeployments>
</scheduledscript>
```

Check out `<status>` and `<recurrence>`. The docs (options) for `<recurrence>` are here: `https://{youAppId}.app.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=SDFxml_2036242651.html`